# Dagger 2 ViewModelProvider.Factory bound multiple times

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to create an application while using fragments. I created a test fragment (HomeFragment) it has only a simple TextView. I created all the necessary classes (module, model and provider). But I'm getting a strange complication error

```
Error:(25, 10) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is bound multiple times:
@Provides android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory app.series.com.series3go.ui.main.MainActivityModule.mainViewModelProvider(app.series.com.series3go.ui.main.MainViewModel)
@Provides android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory app.series.com.series3go.ui.home.HomeFragmentModule.provideHomeFragmentViewModel(app.series.com.series3go.ui.home.HomeFragmentViewModel)
```

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment<HomeFragmentBinding, HomeFragmentViewModel> {

public static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory mViewModelFactory;


HomeFragmentBinding mHomeFragmentBinding;
private HomeFragmentViewModel mHomeFragmentViewModel;

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mHomeFragmentBinding = getViewDataBinding();
    setUp();
    subscribeToLiveData();
}

@Override
public HomeFragmentViewModel getViewModel() {
    mHomeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(HomeFragmentViewModel.class);
    return mHomeFragmentViewModel;
}

@Override
public int getBindingVariable() {
    return BR.viewModel;
}

@Override
public int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.home_fragment;
}

private void setUp() {

}

private void subscribeToLiveData() {

}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}


}
```

**HomeFragmentModule**

```
@Module
public class HomeFragmentModule
{

    @Provides
    HomeFragmentViewModel homeFragmentViewModel()
    {
        return new HomeFragmentViewModel();
    }

    @Provides
    ViewModelProvider.Factory provideHomeFragmentViewModel(HomeFragmentViewModel homeFragmentViewModel)
    {
        return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(homeFragmentViewModel);
    }

}
```

**HomeFragmentProvider**

```
@Module
public abstract class HomeFragmentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = HomeFragmentModule.class)
    abstract HomeFragment provideHomeFragmentFactory();

}
```

**HomeFragmentViewModel**

public class HomeFragmentViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

```
private final ObservableField<String> appVersion = new ObservableField<>();

public HomeFragmentViewModel() {
    super();
    appVersion.set("123");
}

public ObservableField<String> getAppVersion() {
    return appVersion;
}
```

}

home_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="app.series.com.series3go.ui.main.MainActivity">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="app.series.com.series3go.ui.home.HomeFragmentViewModel" />

    </data>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAppVersion"
        style="@style/TextStyle.Title.Sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.appVersion}" />

</layout>
```

Is there a naming convention about function names in provider class(HomeFragmentProvider), 
I didn't see any use of those functions any where in the project. Are they used in the generated classes of dagger?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }

    void inject(SeriesApp app);

}
```

Comment: Also share dagger component.

Comment: updated my main post

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like you have two methods in your dependency graph that provide  `ViewModelProvider.Factory`.

To solve this ambiguity, use `@Named` annotation.

```
@Module
public class HomeFragmentModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("HomeFragment")
    ViewModelProvider.Factory provideHomeFragmentViewModel(HomeFragmentViewModel homeFragmentViewModel) {
        return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(homeFragmentViewModel);
    }
    /* Rest of the code */
}

public class HomeFragment {
    @Inject
    @Named("HomeFragment")
    ViewModelProvider.Factory mViewModelFactory;
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

You should do the same for the second `ViewModelProvider.Factory` too (in `MainActivity` and it's module).

Comment: I added the @Named annotation but I didn't understand where should I use it, it says I need to use it when I use Inject annotation but I don't use it. I just use provides.

Comment: Your solution worked but now viewmodel conflict for activity and fragment in ViemodelFactory. Any idea about this?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan This looks like a separate question on SO

Answer (score 1):

I will edit error log in order to make it a bit more understandable:

> Error: ViewModelProvider.Factory is bound multiple times:
>
> @Provides ViewModelProvider.Factory MainActivityModule.mainViewModelProvider(MainViewModel)
>
> @Provides ViewModelProvider.Factory HomeFragmentModule.provideHomeFragmentViewModel(HomeFragmentViewModel)

You have declared inside `HomeFragment`, that you are willing to inject `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. Dagger tries to find a provider method and finds two of them: one is being provided from `MainActivityModule`, the other from `HomeFragmentModule`. So, dagger gets confused and aborts compilation.

I would suggest you to adopt the approach similar to what is present in Google's showcase [`GithubBrowserSample`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) app. In that app `ViewModels` [are being injected](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.java#L16) into a map (`Map<Class, ViewModel>`) using `@IntoMap` annotation. In your case you would inject `ViewModelProvider.Factory`-ies into map.

You can see the injection of the map inside [`GithubViewModelFactory`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java#L33).

Alternatively, you may consider [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540422/1083957) suggested by @dev.bmax.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit confused, I saw from this example the class ViewModelModule but then I saw at the bottom bindViewModelFactory function, should I also use their GithubViewModelFactory and also I didn't see anyone uses ViewModelModule

Comment: I do not know what exact use case you have, but it seems to me, that most possibly you should **not** need to inject `ViewModelProvider.Factor`-ies, instead you should have one factory and multiple `ViewModel`s.

Comment: I added ViewModelModule with the necessary changes and removed the ViewModelProvider.Factory mainViewModelProvider and ViewModelProvider.Factory provideHomeFragmentViewModel from the modules. I didn't make any changes to my ViewModelProviderFactory and I'm getting errors

Comment: Do you expect me to guess what errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry about that but I couldn't edit my comment because I got an error about updating my comment.

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I applied the solution of dev.bmax